# Dense Rank changes the partition to 1 which is taking long time to save the df

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, dense-rank

I want to map string column to int:

```
st_id  a
a     23
b     34
c     45
b     56
a     5
```

Expected Output:

```
st_id  a   st_id_int
a     23      1
b     34      2
c     45      3
b     56      2
a     5       1
```

So I used dense_rank() and row_number() to get that:

```
df = df.selectExpr('st_id', 'a', 'row_number() over (order by st_id) as st_id_int')
```

But this func changes partiton to just 1, which is creating problem while saving file as  whole stage is just splitting into `1 task`. I even tried to repartion later while saving file but still that stage is just getting split into `1 task`.

Can someone provide the alternative way to `map string to int` or how can I tackle repartition problem.

Can

Comment: do you know what are all possible values for `st_id`?  is it always 1 character?

Comment: No, it's 16 digit alphaneumeric. And I don't know all possible values as it's more that million.

Comment: okay and the integer should be in 1, 2, ... n (n: the # of unique `st_id` value) and also sorted by `st_id`? or is it okay as long as integer is unique amongst different `st_id`?

Comment: It's okay if they're not sorted, as I just want the unique int value for all ```st_id```

Comment: Maybe `F.hash('st_id')`?  this will result in the same integer if you have same string.  and you can add any math equation to make it positive number or smaller number or something you like

Comment: @Emma thank you so much for the answer, can I use f.sha2 for my column. It has 16 characters. Can you please tell me which hash function I should use to get positive integer for 16 character alphaneumeric value

Comment: No.  `sha2` will return string.  only `hash` will return signed int and `xxHash` will return signed `long`.  not sure how safe to do `F.abs(F.hash())` (in terms of number conflicts).  Alternatively, you can try  `F.transform(F.split('st_id'), lambda x: F.ascii(x))` and `concat` later.  `ascii` for alphanumeric should return positive number for sure. This might be still better than `order`ing but I am not sure.

Comment: here is another option. https://masum-math8065.medium.com/how-to-convert-categorical-data-into-numeric-in-pyspark-2202407f5fac. combine with `F.round` for the integer result.

Comment: Are you looking to repartition the data as well to bring all hash values to similar partition?

Comment: @Emma thanks for suggestion. I used hash but for some of the different records it's creating save hash value. Eg
```f073cfcafeaf2778e044001517f43a86 and f00e6dbafa6a46e8e044001517f43a86``` returns same hash value also ```f14c3b1e0c6d0d70e044001517f43a86 and f164cf90cdd75f02e044001517f43a86```
```21c40010cf79457684a4eeaf5a54aa5a and f0f6be325e341d98e0435bd20f0ab420```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to index your string column with repeated hash value. If so, then you can use [StringIndexer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.StringIndexer.html):

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[["a",23],["b",34],["c",45],["b",56],["a",5]], schema=["st_id", "a"])

indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="st_id", outputCol="st_id_int")
df = indexer.fit(df).transform(df).withColumn("st_id_int", F.col("st_id_int").cast("int"))

[Out]:
+-----+---+---------+
|st_id|a  |st_id_int|
+-----+---+---------+
|a    |23 |0        |
|b    |34 |1        |
|c    |45 |2        |
|b    |56 |1        |
|a    |5  |0        |
+-----+---+---------+
```

It returns zero based index, though; but you can add an additional step to increment it by one, if required.

Comment: @Chris_007, does this answer your problem?